# Filter by multiple values on WebGLPointsLayer OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, filtering, openlayers

I try to modify this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon-sprite-webgl.html but I need to filter by multiple values - in my case type of service, region and a few others.

```
const style = {
  variables: {
  filterType: "all",
  filterRegion: "all",
},
  filter: [
    "any",
    ["==", ["var", "filterType"], "all"],
    ["==", ["var", "filterRegion"], "all"],
    ["==", ["var", "filterType"], ["get", "type"]],
    ["==", ["var", "filterRegion"], ["get", "region"]],
  ]
}

const map = new Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [
  new TileLayer({
    source: new OSM(),
  }),
  new WebGLPointsLayer({
    source: pinsLayer,
    style: style,
  }),
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: fromLonLat([15.5, 49.4]),
    zoom: 8,
  }),
});
```

And I control the dropdown filtering like this

```
const typeSelect = document.getElementById("type-filter");
regionSelect.addEventListener("input", function () {
  style.variables.filterType = typeSelect.value;
  map.render();
});
const regionSelect = document.getElementById("region-filter");
regionSelect.addEventListener("input", function () {
  style.variables.filterRegion = regionSelect.value;
  map.render();
});
```

But the filtering seems to be random, there is probably an issue with the conditions but I don't know how to debug this or find info in the docs on the syntax. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Instead of `map.render()` you need to call `layer.updateStyleVariables()` for example as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cog-stretch.html